# Overloading getMessageName of ViewRootImpl class

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to inherit ViewRootImpl system class for getMessageName method overloading?

```
  final class ViewRootHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public String getMessageName(Message message) {
  .....
```

If it's not possible, how can I obtain the result, which is returned by getMessageName method?

Comment: What do you need it for??

Comment: I want to log in file everything, what getMessageName returns during application execution.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that , the only thing you can do is to call Looper.setMessageLogging

Comment: Is it possible to do using C++?

Comment: I have ZERO experience with ndk,  sorry